# Pivot table creations

Tags: excel, vbscript, excel-2007, vba

I have a doubt that can one sheet have multiple Pivot tables? If so is there any way to define their names in the sheet?

I wrote the below code to update/Refresh the Pivot tables defined on different sheets,but gettings following error:

```
 Dim objExcel1,strPathExcel1
 Dim objSheet1,objSheet2,objSheet3

 Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 strPathExcel1 = "D:\AravoVB\Copy of Original    Scripts\CopyofGEWingtoWing_latest_dump_21112012.xls"

objExcel1.Workbooks.open(strPathExcel1)
Set objSheet1 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Business Process Matrix")
Set objSheet2 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Workflow Status Matrix")
Set objSheet3 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Business Hierarchy Martix")

objSheet1.PivotTables(1).PivotCache.Refresh
objSheet2.PivotTables(1).PivotCache.Refresh
objSheet3.PivotTables(1).PivotCache.Refresh
```

***ERROR :*** *Subscript out of range*

Can you help me here?

***UPDATE***

I have a data Excel sheet in the below format:

```
Name   Fruits    Condition of Fruits
=====  ======    ====================

Ram    Apple       Good

Jadu   Apple       Bad

Tina   Orange      Good

Ram    Orange      Good

Tina   Apple       Bad

Ram    Apple       Bad
```

Output of the Pivot program in the other sheet of the same excel, say in sheet(2) should be 
like this:

```
Name  Fruits   Condition of Fruits
====  ======   ===================
               Good       Bad    Total
               ====      =====  ======
Ram   Apple     1           1     2
Ram   Orange    1           0     1
Tina  Apple     0           1     1
Tina  Orange    1           0     1
jadu  Apple     0           1     1
===================================
Grand Total     3           3     6
===================================
```

The above format needs to be present in the Excel in the sheet(2), whenever sheet(1) will be having source data within it as shown in the first table.

I want Macro program to create using Excel pivot table concept.

Can you suggest any code settings, for the above Pivot creation?

Thanks

Comment: Please see my update! and help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can any suggest me what I need to do here to eliminate such error?

Comment: Please use the debugger to see which statement exactly causes the error. I am speculating now ... in a collection like PivotTables() the first indexed element has index 0, so maybe - if there is only 1 table per sheet, the index=1 is higher than what you have, hence "Subscript out of range"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple Pivot tables in one single sheet. Create them, then right-click them, select "Pivot Table Options ..." and view/change their names. Normally you don't need to do this, as Excel automatically names the tables [PivotTable***N***] with ***N*** being 1, 2, 3, ...

However you should avoid having multiple Pivots in a single sheet if you often change their look (e.g. add or remove columns and/or rows)

EDIT: in response to your comment ... yes you can ... in Excel2010.VBA the relevant objects/methods are

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=..., SourceData:= ..., Version:=...).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=..., TableName:=..., DefaultVersion:=...
```

The Source data is defined through the PivotCache object, destination defined through the concatenated CreatePivotTable method.

Later on you use

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(...).PivotFields(...).Orientation and .position
```

and

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(...).AddDataField ...PivotFields(...), "header", xlSum
```

to specify your Pivot table design.

Best is to start recording a macro, create a Pivot table, stop the recorder and examine the generated code.

Comment: Thanks for your help,But one more query I do have,is that Can we create Pivot table programmitacally?

Comment: what about the subscript error? did you fix it? Please open a new request instead of updating this case and changing the subject. For your new problem I suggest  you manually create the sample pivot table under the control of the macro recorder as described and examine the code produced.

Comment: Yes,That issue has been fixed,I used pivot table name in place of subscripts.